# HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/

Tags: solidity, infura, brownie

I'm getting this error

```
Brownie v1.15.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftMixProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 43, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 55, in connect
    p._load_deployments()
  File "brownie/project/main.py", line 357, in _load_deployments
    contract = ProjectContract(self, build, build_json.stem)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 1291, in __init__
    _DeployedContractBase.__init__(self, address, owner, tx)
  File "brownie/network/contract.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.bytecode = web3.eth.get_code(address).hex()[2:]
  File "web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "web3/manager.py", line 180, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "web3/manager.py", line 141, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py", line 80, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "web3/middleware/attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 76, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 74, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "web3/middleware/buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "web3/middleware/exception_retry_request.py", line 104, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "web3/providers/rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "web3/_utils/request.py", line 49, in make_post_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `PRIVATE_KEY` is likely set to an empty string.

Do you have a `.env` file with:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=XXXXX
```

and then in your brownie config:

```
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, the problem was with my project id. I accidently added an extra 's' at the end. Kindly verify your project id.

Answer (score 0):

- dropping this comment for future encounters
  Make sure there is no space around the = operator. I spend a good amount of time finding out the possible causes. That was a type error introduced accidentally.
  .`env`

  export PRIVATE_KEY=0xXXXXX

  export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=Your_Infura_Project_Id